# How to access object field in server array response?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, parse-platform

I made a `parse.com` get request, the returned data is stored in:

```
$scope.tastes = data.results
    {
        "createdAt": "2016-03-16T07:39:15.745Z",
        "objectId": "Cmg8GdOv2Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-03-16T07:39:15.745Z",
        "user": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "_User",
            "objectId": "vYOsndWlto"
        },
        "userTastes": [
            {
                "actualite": {
                    "checked": true
                },
                "economie": {
                    "checked": true
                },
                "entrepreneuriat": {
                    "checked": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Well, I want to get userTastes array.

I've tried

```
    .success(function (data, status) {
      $scope.tastes = data.results.userTastes;
      console.log($scope.tastes);
    })
```

However nothing is returned. I think that I'm missing something.

**My question : How do I get userTastes in $scope.tastes ?**

Comment: Did you try `this.proxy(function)` or bind the context to the function?

Comment: Will data.results[0].userTastes work?, Have you tried console logging to see if data is returning anything?

Comment: how if `data.userTastes` ?

Comment: Without a basic example whats going on it's hard to say. Can you provide a fiddle? @Jry9972 You can only comment with 50+ rep...which I got right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I writing a separate answer because I believe this needs further explanation and not just the fix to your problem.

You only provided an object response in your question, but apparently you are getting an array response from your server, while you can directly access object fields, on array objects you need to access the position first, Ex:

```
$scope.objectResponse = {"foo":"bar"};
console.log($scope.objectResponse.foo); // Will print "bar"
```

in contrast array responses:

```
$scope.arrayResponse = [{"foo":"bar"}];
console.log($scope.arrayResponse[0].foo); // Will print "bar"
```

Just make sure you are getting the response you want from your server.

Answer (score 0):

results[0].userTastes work worked perfectly **thanks !**

If someone have a tutorial link or good course about array and objects in JS because I'm a little bit confused about that.

Have a good day !